# Why does SE remind me about bounties I can't do anything about?

Tags: discussion, bounties, notifications

I understand the value in reminding me that my bounty is expiring soon. I don't understand the value in doing so when the question has *no answers*. I can't award the bounty; I can't ask someone to improve their answer or clarify some point. I can't offer another bounty on the question (until after this one expires).

Answer (score 4):

All the same, you might bump the post to the front page by editing. That's what I think.

Also, there are other ways to increase interest in the question, like by mentioning it in chat:

> "Hey! The bounty on [this interesting question](http://example.com/) is almost up!"

Comment: Also, it can prompt you to spread the link to your social networks or other people who might be able to answer but who aren't SE regulars.  (And hey, even if you don't get an answer, you might at least get an Announcer badge. :-) )